# Counting number of steps throughout the circle

Tags: java

The method public static int steps(int posts, int stride) calculates how many strides can be taken to get back to posts.

Let's say if the method is `(12, 4)`, it takes only three steps.

Now let's say the method has parameters `(12,5)`, so it should be `(5, 10, 3, 8, 1, 6, 11, 4, 9, 2, 7, 12)`. My method works for such examplse as `(12, 4)` or `(12,3)` or `(6,2)`... but how can I figure out `(12,5)`?

```
public static int steps(int posts, int stride)
{
     int countSteps = 0;
     int result = 0;
     do
     {
         result += stride; 

       /*  if((result > posts) || (result < posts))
         {

         }*/
         countSteps++;
     }
     while(result != posts);
     return countSteps;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `stride` is never greater than `posts`, the simplest way is to add a bounds-check:

```
if (result > posts) {
    result -= posts;
}
```

(so, for example, if you find yourself at `result == 13`, the above will subtract 12 in order to bring you back to `result == 1`.)

If that assumption is not always correct, then a more general approach is to use the "remainder" operator `%`, which computes the remainder after performing integer division. For example, the remainder after dividing 28 by 12 is 4, so `28 % 12 == 4`. In your case, that gives you:

```
result = (result - 1) % posts + 1;
```

which subtracts 1 in order to get 0-based positions instead of 1-based, then computes the remainder after dividing by 12 in order to "normalize" to the range 0–11, and then adds 1 again in order to restore the 1-based numbering.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But would you please explain what do you mean 0-based positions ?

Comment: @Inferno: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering. I mean having positions numbered 0 through *n*-1 rather than 1 through *n*.

Comment: This doesn't work in the case that `stride > 2*posts`. Changing the `if` to `while` fixes this, however (assuming that `stride` and `posts` are positive, that is).

Comment: @AndyTurner: It sounds like you've just looked at the first code snippet, without actually reading any of the rest of the answer. :-/

Answer (score -1):

```
while(result != posts){
   result += stride; 

   if (result > posts){
      int extraSteps = result - posts;
      result = 0 + extraSteps;
   }
}
```

not tested, but try this.

Comment: This has been flagged as low quality post. It would help if you provide an explanation as to how your code answers the question.